# Setting parameter value through a URL object vs setting as string

Tags: javascript, java

In IDE it is possible to set value of (connector) parameter through JavaScript.
Note: The IDE is IBM Security Directory Integrator (SDI). It is an eclipse based IDE that provides to write Java & JavaScript to perform ETL related activities. Since the questions is related to Java & JavaScript I believe if someone from Java/JavaScripts can help me understand the difference.

For eg: To set url parameter

```
// Get AL config object.
var gALCfg = task.getConfigClone(); //task is an in-built object provided in SDI

// Get AL settings object from AL config.
var gALSettings = gALCfg.getSettings();

// Get Parameters from TCB
var WSDLurl = gALSettings.getStringParameter("erPOSWSDLlocation");    ///we get the wsdl URL in this step.
var myURL = WSDL;
```

URL field on a connector can now be set with 'var myURL'

What difference would it make if I create a URL object and then set value of the (connector) parameter ? For eg:

```
var gALCfg = task.getConfigClone(); //task is an in-built object provided in SDI
var gALSettings = gALCfg.getSettings();
var WSDLurl = gALSettings.getStringParameter("erPOSWSDLlocation");    //we get the wsdl URL in this step.

var myURL = new Packages.java.net.URL(WSDL);
```